# Saxon 9.6.0.7 version also needs saxon-dom?

Tags: java, xslt, dom, saxon

I was upgrading the version of my saxon dependency and the project can't run because I'm using DOMSource instance to make a transformation.

```
public String getXML(Node objNode) throws Exception{
     Transformer t = ThreadLocalHelper.getDomTransformer().get();
     t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
     StringWriter w = new StringWriter(4096);
     t.transform(new DOMSource(objNode), new StreamResult(w));
     return w.toString();
}
```

There is another way to transform a Node/Document in saxon 9.6?

Thanks

Comment: This code should work "out of the box", with all Saxon editions including Saxon-HE. How is it failing? (Do be aware, however, that using a DOM for Saxon input is much slower than allowing Saxon to use its own native tree format).

Comment: Your mention of "saxon-dom" suggests that perhaps you previously used an older Saxon release in which the DOM support code was part of a separate JAR? That separation was done to cope with historical incompatibilities between JDK releases which are no longer relevant, so the DOM code was integrated back into the main JAR file.

Comment: Yes, thats what i tought. About the DOMSource, I don't know other way to do this transformation, since I need to transform a Node object. And yes I was using the 9.1 version.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When a DOMSource is used, saxon9-dom.jar must be on the classpath

Comment: Saxon DOM support was in a separate JAR file in 9.1, but this is no longer the case in 9.6. The message you are quoting comes from an older release.

Answer (score -1):

I am using:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result result = new StreamResult(bos);

// Transform into HTML
try {
    transformer.transform(xmlDocument, result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    // do stuff
}
```

with xmlDocument as a StreamSource:

```
xmlDocument = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(encoding)))
```

Using saxon 9.6.0-7

Comment: The problem is that I receive a Node object that needs to be transformed.
Is there anyway that I can cast a Node to a streamSource?